# Unable to refer one json schema into another json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

[array3.schema.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciJGy.png)[Error I get when I do hit and try with wrong paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMc3x.png)[Folder stricture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxEoK.png)

I have array2.schema.json which is a schema and I want to refer this schema in array3.schema.json file. 
I have tried file:/// absolutepath//array2.schema.json but I want to use the relative path.
So instead of file:///D://GIT_Repo//IOTRemoteLab_Sharma_Shubham//D1//D1_1//array2.schema.json, I want to use something like file:///D1//D1_1//array2.schema.json so that I can always validate using array2.schema.json if both are together in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the same directory, just use the filename on its own: `{ "$ref": "array2.schema.json" }`

Comment: it shows unknown url type.. can you tell me how do I validate this ?? currently I am using Python validator.. from jsonschema import validate
!jsonschema -i array3.json array3.schema.json.... File "C:\Users\abrok\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'array2.schema.json'

Comment: JSON Schema itself knows nothing about files in a file system on a disk. Some implementations load files from disk for convenience, but the expectation is you need to load in all your schema files manually, using `$id` values to idenfity each one.

Comment: Then how do I solve it ?? provide "$id":"array2_schemid" in array2.schema.json and use $ref: array2_schemaid in array3.schema.json ?? this also does not work

Comment: That sounds like a bug you should report directly to the implementation that you are using.